# -webkit-animation bug

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-animations

I have been designing a webpage which has a container with a specific width and this contains floated divs inside. I have a webkit animation on these, which is tied with a hover, however when you float over the last div of a line, it seems to add spaces on the next for no reason. I tried this in firefox and it works ok, so seems to be a webkit bug - it shows in both Safari & Chrome. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J292V/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by changing the divs from float:left to display:inline-block and defining the to and from on the animations. The above is definitely a bug, but here is the workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/J292V/3/